# In abelian groups: Is $[G:2G]\leq 2$?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be an abelian group. Is it true that $[G:2G]\leq 2$?

Sometimes it can be $1$ (say, when $G=\mathbb{Z}_3$), but it seems never to be more than $2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Given any two abelian groups $G$ and $H$, if we let $K=G\times H$, then $2K=2G\times 2H$, and
$$K/2K\cong (G/2G)\times(H/2H).$$
What does this mean about the cardinality of $K/2K$, i.e., the index $[K:2K]$? Does that give you any ideas for finding a counterexample to your conjecture?

Comment: Yes, the Klein 4-group. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to help!${}$

Comment: Alternate hint: consider the case that $2G$ is trivial.

Comment: @Ask: What happens if you consider $\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$ of the product of two non divisible groups?